# In ArcGIS 10.1, for what tools does Environments actually work?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, arctoolbox

As a new user, often I have used "active" (that is, not grayed out and non-functional) Environments when using ArcToolbox Tools and the operation is non-responsive. I wish I documented for my own record what I have seen along the way, but have not, still being somewhat confused as to whether it is because I am doing something wrong. Following are two recent examples.

1) Using a raster, I have seen where

```
Spatial Analyst > Extract by Polygon > Environments > Raster Analysis 
and changing the cell size will not change the cell size;
```

and

2) using a raster

```
Data Management > Resample > Environments > Raster Analysis > 
Mask will change the cell size but not mask.
```

Since the combination of operations that are not allowed by ArcGIS do not result in grayed out inactive buttons or a warning message, is there some list that tells what Environment operations can and can't be done with the various ArcToolbox Tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the bottom of the help page for each tool, ESRI provides a list of the environments that can impact the tool's processing.

For example, the [Resample help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/resample.htm) does not include Mask in its list. It does not include Cell Size in its list either, because the cell size option that is a direct and required input to the tool would overwrite it anyway.

The [Extract By Polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-polygon.htm) page does list Cell Size in its environments. If it's not working for you, submit a bug report to ESRI. I just tested it in 10.3.1, and it works just as advertised.